# Get all records in first tbl and matching in second tbl (indicating ones that existed)

Tags: mysql

Looking to get ALL `UserName` from `UsersDataTbl` and matching `UserName` from `EnrollmentsTbl` if it exist. but I want to identify which ones exist in the `EnrollmentsTbl` and not create 2 records. Maybe add a boolean expression that gets `1` if exist and `0` if not.

my SQL is returning only existing record in `EnrollmentsTbl`

```
SELECT u.UserName
     , e.Completed 
  FROM UsersDataTbl u
  LEFT 
  JOIN EnrollmentsTbl e
    ON u.UserName = e.UserName 
 WHERE e.ClassName LIKE 'Word%' 
   AND u.UserName LIKE 'bar%'
```

ADDITIONAL QUESTION:

```
(SELECT u.UserName, u.LastName, d.Station
  , (e.UserName IS NOT NULL) as completedl 
  FROM UsersDataTbl u
  LEFT 
  JOIN EnrollmentsTbl e
    ON u.UserName = e.UserName 
        AND e.ClassName LIKE 'Word%') 
  INNER JOIN UsersDataCareerTbl d 
  ON u.UserName = d.UserName
  WHERE u.Career = 1 AND Active = 1 ORDER BY u.LastName
```

Comment: Note `LEFT JOIN x... WHERE x=...` is the same as `INNER JOIN x...`

Comment: note sure who keeps editing my code - but SQL is not correct anymore???

Comment: I made it readable. I made no structural changes.

Comment: There's no additional question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can us the `is not null` to test if a field's value is null or not and return a true or false. If the username does not exist in `EnrollmentsTbl` then the left join will return `null` in its place.

I moved the `e.ClassName LIKE 'Word%` criterion from the `where` clause to the join condition, since it changed the `left join` into an `inner join` defeating the whole purpose of the query.

```
SELECT u.UserName
     , (e.UserName IS NOT NULL) as user_exists_in_EnrollmentsTbl 
  FROM UsersDataTbl u
  LEFT 
  JOIN EnrollmentsTbl e
    ON u.UserName = e.UserName 
        AND e.ClassName LIKE 'Word%'
 WHERE u.UserName LIKE 'bar%'
```

Comment: can you help me with the update above - need to link another table onto the current working example.

Comment: If you have another question, then ask it as a separate question.

Comment: ok see new question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42322584/join-second-table-to-working-example