# JOIN second table to working example

Tags: mysql

looking to join another table onto existing working example:

Working SQL:

```
SELECT u.UserName, u.LastName
     , (e.UserName IS NOT NULL) as user_exists_in_EnrollmentsTbl 
  FROM UsersDataTbl u
  LEFT 
  JOIN EnrollmentsTbl e
    ON u.UserName = e.UserName 
        AND e.ClassName LIKE 'Word%'
 WHERE u.Career = 1 AND Active = 1 ORDER BY u.LastName
```

My Attempt:

```
(SELECT u.UserName, u.LastName, d.Station
  , (e.UserName IS NOT NULL) as completedl 
  FROM UsersDataTbl u
  LEFT 
  JOIN EnrollmentsTbl e
    ON u.UserName = e.UserName 
        AND e.ClassName LIKE 'Word%') 
  INNER JOIN UsersDataCareerTbl d 
  ON u.UserName = d.UserName
  WHERE u.Career = 1 AND Active = 1 ORDER BY u.LastName
```

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve here?

Comment: JOIN the `UsersDataCareerTbl` to the existing and get `Station` in results

Answer (score 0):

figured it out:

```
SELECT u.UserName, u.LastName, d.Station, (e.UserName IS NOT NULL) as completed 
  FROM (UsersDataTbl u
INNER JOIN UsersDataCareerTbl d ON u.UserName = d.UserName)  
LEFT 
  JOIN EnrollmentsTbl e
    ON u.UserName = e.UserName 
        AND e.ClassName LIKE 'Word%' 
 WHERE u.Career = 1 AND Active = 1 ORDER BY u.LastName
```

Comment: I would have used c as the alias, and qualified active. But yep, that looks like it